# reactjs html rendering as string not html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase

Trying to render html but I'm getting strings

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('raffle/');
ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  var content = ``;
  var IDwrapper = document.getElementById('raffleFeed');

  snapshot.forEach((data) => {
    // var rImage = data.val().raffleImage;
    var rTitle = data.val().raffleTitle;
    var rAmount = data.val().raffleAmount;
    var rDescription = data.val().raffleDescription;
    var rEntries = data.val().raffleEntries;
    var rButton = '<button class="btn btn-secondary"> Button </button>';

    console.log(data.val());
    // content += '<Row>';
    content += '<Col sm="4">';
    content += '<CardBody>';

    content += '<CardTitle>' + rTitle + '</CardTitle>';
    content += '<CardText>' + rAmount + '</CardText>';
    content += '<CardText>' + rEntries + '</CardText>';
    content += '<CardText>' + rDescription + '</CardText>';
    content += rButton;

    content += '</CardBody>';
    content += '</Col>';
    // content += '</Row>'; //end
  });

  IDwrapper.append(content);
```

the following is rendered

> <Col
>   sm="4"><CardBody><CardTitle>1</CardTitle><CardText>1</CardText><CardText>1</CardText><CardText>1</CardText><button
>   class="btn btn-secondary"> Button
>   </button></CardBody></Col><Col
>   sm="4"><CardBody><CardTitle>2</CardTitle><CardText>2</CardText><CardText>2</CardText><CardText>2</CardText><button
>   class="btn btn-secondary"> Button
>   </button></CardBody></Col><Col
>   sm="4"><CardBody><CardTitle>3</CardTitle><CardText>3</CardText><CardText>3</CardText><CardText>3</CardText><button
>   class="btn btn-secondary"> Button
>   </button></CardBody></Col><Col
>   sm="4"><CardBody><CardTitle>4</CardTitle><CardText>4</CardText><CardText>4</CardText><CardText>4</CardText><button
>   class="btn btn-secondary"> Button
>   </button></CardBody></Col><Col
>   sm="4"><CardBody><CardTitle>5</CardTitle><CardText>5</CardText><CardText>5</CardText><CardText>5</CardText><button
>   class="btn btn-secondary"> Button
>   </button></CardBody></Col>

not sure what I'm overlooking but its driving me insane. thanks for the help

Comment: This seems to be achievable easily using react only, your HTML can be rendred using jsx

Comment: @Justcode can you show me in code? im confused somewhere

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve create small demo

Comment: just trying to loop thru my `firebase database` and render the values to the view @Justcode

Comment: Can you create demo on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: Another option is to use react-html-parser - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser. I use this to convert my WordPress API responses to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push your JSX into an `array`, or use a React `Fragment`, or worst case scenario, use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`.

Here's a simple example of using mixed array content (`string`s plus `JSX`):
https://codesandbox.io/s/1v1xmq1kmq

Same example as above, however, instead of using an array, just wrapping the content within a `Fragment`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/92r12m7zp

Here's a more complex example using a chunked array (change the `columns` to a number that divides into 24 evenly): https://codesandbox.io/s/30v7qvoz3m

Example of using an array:

```
const content = [];

snapshot.forEach((data) => {
  const rTitle = data.val().raffleTitle;
  const rAmount = data.val().raffleAmount;
  const rDescription = data.val().raffleDescription;
  const rEntries = data.val().raffleEntries;
  const rButton = <button class="btn btn-secondary"> Button </button>

  const jsxContent = (
    <Row key={rTitle}>
      <Col sm="4">
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle> { rTitle }</CardTitle>
           ...etc
        <CardBody>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  )

  content.push(jsxContent);
});
```

Then in your React component:

```
<div>
 {content}
</div>
```

---

Usually the database will store a `JSON` array of raffle ticket data like so:

```
[ 
  { 
    id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx (unique uuid), 
    title: "Example Raffle Title", 
    amount: 10.00, 
    description: "Example raffle description", 
    entries: 49, 
    maxEntries: 500 
  }, 
  { 
    id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx,
    title: "Example Raffle Title 2",  
    ...etc 
  }, 
  {
    ...etc
  } 
]
```

Then you'll retrieve this `JSON` array from your database, map over the array, display each item, and apply a unique `id` to an element's `onClick` handler (click on one of the tickets to retrieve the `id`, which then can be used to charge the customer, update the database `entries`, ...etc).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/8446420yn2

Comment: is this the traditional react way of displaying database nodes to your view?

Answer (score 0):

`content` is just a string, but you need a `node`.

If it is an option, you may try this

```
 IDwrapper.innerHTML = content;
```

Comment: so how would i `append` but render the `HTML tags` with my object variables values?

Comment: If you are using REACT.JS, you need to `return()` all that through react`s `render()` instead of directly appending to DOM.
Everything you want to be reactive, must go through react.

Answer (score 0):

create an object `var cardValues = {}` and assign the various `snapshot` values to this object, e.g. `cardValues.title = snapshot.val().title`. Then, pass this object to a card builder function that uses `document.createElement` and `.appendChild` methods to render out your cards.